# Wicket 6 Invalidate Session in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, session, wicket

I'm working on a Wicket app that needs to log out the user when they close the browser or click a link to another site. I found [Invalidate Wicket session after displaying message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772671/invalidate-wicket-session-after-displaying-message) and rotsch's answer, which was a great foundation. My problem now, though, is to use that ability to call javascript to invalidate the session. 
This is my attempt at the js call to invalidate the session:

```
public class PageExitBehaviour extends Behavior{

@Override
public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(component, response);
    response.render(new OnDomReadyHeaderItem("window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {"
            + "getSession().invalidate();" + "};"));

}
```

Does anyone know what to put in after "window.onbeforeunload = " to make it call getSession().invalidate()? Or does anyone know some other way to log out a user when they close the browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the session is managed on the server side, you have to send an AJAX request to the server when the user leaves the page. The following Behavior implementation does just that.

```
public class PageExitLogoutBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

  @Override
  public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(component, response);
    response.render(new OnDomReadyHeaderItem(String.format(
            "window.onbeforeunload = function(e){ %s };",
            this.getCallbackScript())));
  }

  @Override
  protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    System.out.println("logging out...");
    target.getPage().getSession().invalidate();
  }

}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much, and thanks for the clarification about needing AJAX.

Comment: Hello Tom, I would like to know if your approach fits also for a Wicket web application with multi tab opened on the browser side. How could I implement the same mechanism when user close the entire browser screen and not just on of the tabs opened? Thanks a lot :)